# how can i pass input parameter with single quote in Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

i have a stored procedure r, i'm passing the below string but it's not working??

```
call Prc_SearchKeyword('randomize', "'girl', 'playing'",2,0,31);
```

the below syntax is working fine..

```
call Prc_SearchKeyword('randomize', 'girl',1,0,31);



DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `Prc_SearchKeyword`(IN filter VARCHAR(50), IN midquery varchar(200), IN keywordcount int(10), In firstimage int(10), in lastimage int(10) )
BEGIN
IF(filter = 'nbofviews') Then
SELECT sd.imageid, sd.imgcollection, sd.Caption FROM   (SELECT p.imageid  FROM searchinitial_views p join searchkwdmgmt s on p.primarykeyword = s.primary_kwd and s.allkwd in (midquery) GROUP  BY p.imageid HAVING Count(distinct p.primarykeyword) = keywordcount order by views desc  LIMIT  firstimage, lastimage ) q join searchdetails sd ON sd.imageid = q.imageid ;
END IF;
IF(filter = 'shootdate') Then
SELECT sd.imageid, sd.imgcollection, sd.Caption FROM   (SELECT p.imageid  FROM searchinitial_shootdate p join searchkwdmgmt s on p.primarykeyword = s.primary_kwd and s.allkwd in (midquery) GROUP  BY p.imageid HAVING Count(distinct p.primarykeyword) = keywordcount order by shootdate desc  LIMIT  firstimage, lastimage ) q join searchdetails sd ON sd.imageid = q.imageid ;
END IF;
IF(filter = 'randomize') Then
SELECT sd.imageid, sd.imgcollection, sd.Caption FROM   (SELECT p.imageid  FROM searchinitial_random p join searchkwdmgmt s on p.primarykeyword = s.primary_kwd and s.allkwd in (midquery) GROUP  BY p.imageid HAVING Count(distinct p.primarykeyword) = keywordcount order by random desc  LIMIT  firstimage, lastimage ) q join searchdetails sd ON sd.imageid = q.imageid;
END IF;
IF(filter = 'priority') Then
SELECT sd.imageid, sd.imgcollection, sd.Caption FROM   (SELECT p.imageid  FROM searchinitial_priority p join searchkwdmgmt s on p.primarykeyword = s.primary_kwd and s.allkwd in (midquery) GROUP  BY p.imageid HAVING Count(distinct p.primarykeyword) = keywordcount order by priority desc  LIMIT  firstimage, lastimage ) q join searchdetails sd ON sd.imageid = q.imageid ;
END IF;
END
```

Comment: You need to lookup how to escape characters

Comment: The problem is that you expect `s.allkwd IN (midquery)` to split the parameter into multiple strings. You need to write dynamic SQL to perform string substitution like this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to lookup how to escape characters i.e. use two single quotes instead of one `''girl'',''playing''`

Answer (score 0):

You can escape single quotes with two single quotes: 
for example:

```
... where lastname='O''Malley'
```

in your case:

```
''girl'',''playing''
```

Answer (score -1):

Since MySQL recognizes both single and double quotes as string delimiters, one option is to use double quotes when you want to include single quotes in the value, or vice versa.

```
call YourProc("'girl', 'playing'");
```

The alternative is to escape the quotes with backslash:

```
call YourProc('\'girl\', \'playing\'');
```